# Firebase functions change names when deploying

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

I have been working with functions for a while, recently I made a function called "unPublishStore" in my index.js file.
When calling `firebase deploy --only functions` every thing runs flawlessly, but the function's name gets changed, where in the cmd it shows the following:

[image]

and in the firebase's functions list the name is also changed:

[image]

Comment: please share the code, also try deploying specific function `firebase deploy --only functions:FunctionName`

Answer (score 0):

This feels very much like a typo error.

Please check you index file, ensure the definition name on the left side:

```
exports.functionNameToDeploy = functionYouWrote;
```

The `functionNameToDeploy` will exactly be the name shown in cloud instead of the `functionYouWrote`

Probably you can search globally in your project to see if there is a function called `upPublishStore`?